# powershell: displaying array data next to string data?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When i open the export below in excel, all i can see for MemberOf is System.String[].  How can i show each member with the name, description, userprincipalname next to it?

```
$Accounts | Get-QADUser | ft name, description, UserPrincipalName, memberOf | Export-Csv C:\Temp\Useraccounts.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Accounts | Get-QADUser | select  name, description, UserPrincipalName, @{ n="memberof"; e={ $_.memberof }}  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\file.csv
```

Some info for 'calculated property' [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)

Some info for ['why-can-t-i-pipe-format-table-to-export-csv-and-get-something-useful'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/03/07/why-can-t-i-pipe-format-table-to-export-csv-and-get-something-useful.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Join the group names and use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table` before you export to csv:

```
$Accounts | Get-QADUser | Select-Object Name,Description,UserPrincipalName,@{ n="memberOf"; e={ $_.memberOf -join ';' }} | Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: Is better a different delimitator from ';'. Something as " | " if csv is opened in excel.