# PowerShell exporting csv / Strange output

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm quite new to PowerShell and not the greatest one on working with code and scripts but trying to learn. And now to the problem!

I've wrote a short script, that lists all user's of a specific OU with certain properties.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=XY,OU=XY,OU=XY,OU=XY,DC=XY,DC=XY” -Properties DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed, AccountExpirationDate, Company, StreetAddress, L, PostalCode, co | 
    select DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, @{ Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed") } }, AccountExpirationDate, Company, StreetAddress, L, PostalCode, co | 
    Sort-Object -Property Company | 
    Format-Table -Autosize -Property Company, DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, ExpiryDate, StreetAddress, L, Postalcode, co
```

This works fine, when in run the script in powershell, everything gets displayed properly, but when i try to export the information to a csv file:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=XY,OU=XYs,OU=XY,OU=XY,DC=XY,DC=XY” -Properties DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed, AccountExpirationDate, Company, StreetAddress, L, PostalCode, co | 
    select DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, @{ Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed") } }, AccountExpirationDate, Company, StreetAddress, L, PostalCode, co | 
    Sort-Object -Property Company | 
    Format-Table -Autosize -Property Company, DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, ExpiryDate, StreetAddress, L, Postalcode, co | 
    Export-Csv -Path c:\xy.csv
```

I get some strange caracters in the file like this:

```
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c,,,,,
```

But this only happen after a certain amount of properties/columns have been selected for the table. I only choose 4 properties it works fine. What am I missing?

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Comment: I think you don't need `Format-Table` here, since you export to CSV. Does it work better if you remove this bit ? `Format-Table -Autosize -Property Company, DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, ExpiryDate, StreetAddress, L, Postalcode, co | `

Comment: In addition to @sodawillow's comment (which is correct / is the cause of your strange output), you may want to add the `-notype` (or `-NoTypeInformation`) switch to your `Export-CSV` call; that'll ensure the first row is headers rather than the `#TYPE ...` line.  See http://ss64.com/ps/export-csv.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Powershell, what is the proper way to select data from a FormatTable to manipulate it as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130603/in-powershell-what-is-the-proper-way-to-select-data-from-a-formattable-to-manip)

Comment: The dupe talks about using Format-Cmdlets as output. Trying to see if there is a better one.

Comment: @Matt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906583/powershell-displaying-array-data-next-to-string-data/9906849#9906849

Comment: @JoelKönig: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/03/07/why-can-t-i-pipe-format-table-to-export-csv-and-get-something-useful.aspx for more info

Comment: What column do those characters show up under in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Format-*` cmdlets should generally be last in the pipeline.

If you remove the `Format-Table` bit in your snippet, you should get the expected result.

Also, `-NoTypeInformation` is your best friend when using `Export-CSV` :-) *credits to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt)*

Answer (score -2):

Could you try out-file command?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=XY,OU=XYs,OU=XY,OU=XY,DC=XY,DC=XY” -Properties DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed, AccountExpirationDate, Company, StreetAddress, L, PostalCode, co | select DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, @{ Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed") } }, AccountExpirationDate, Company, StreetAddress, L, PostalCode, co | Sort-Object -Property Company | Format-Table -Autosize -Property Company, DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, ExpiryDate, StreetAddress, L, Postalcode, co | out-file -filepath c:\xy.csv
```

Comment: The op is asking about csv's. This won't do that.

Comment: How is this an answer? The op wants to export the output to .csv extension file. Out-file does not realize that

Comment: @GünerHacıoğlu Can you show your command creating a csv? As of now it does not.

Comment: I used a sharepoint site role assignment export. this is sample code:   `code`$myweb =  Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint-site" 
$mylist = $myweb.Lists | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq 'SharedDocuments' }
foreach ($item in $mylist.Items ){
$item.Url | out-file -Append -filepath "C:\permissions.csv"
out-file -append -filepath "C:\permissions.csv" -inputobject   $item.RoleAssignments -width 150
}`code`

Comment: @ sodawillow: Thanks for your quick answer! Without the fomat-table command it did work out. Thanks alot!!

Comment: Without `Format-CSV`, `Out-File` does not generate CSV format.